# How can I use the array_map with callback function as a member of array element?

Tags: php

Can I use array_map to replace this code:

```
$points = [];
foreach($addresses as $address) $points[] = $address->getRoutePoint();
$this->points = $points;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing particular to do:

```
$this->points = array_map(function($i) { return $i->getRoutePoint(); }, $addresses);
```

However, using `foreach` is faster and you don't need to use the `$points` variable:

```
$this->points = [];
foreach($addresses as $address) {
    $this->points[] = $address->getRoutePoint();
}
```